# A lock that decides which function may be called

Tags: design-patterns

I have 3 classes: `A`, `B` and `C` where both `B` and `C` inherit from `A`. Both `B` and `C` need to implement a method called `prepare` which may be called `x` times and once the preparation stage is done, the function `final_calculation` may be called. I was thinking of making both classes have a `boolean` which toggles, depending on whether or not we are in the preparation stage. If we are in the preparation stage, only the `prepare` function can be called, else only the `final_calculation` function. So `A` would look something like this:

```
class A:

def __init__(self):
    self.prepare_state = True

def toggle_state(self):
    self.prepare_state = not self.prepare_state

def prepare(self):
    if self.prepare_state is False:
        raise StateError

def final_calculation(self):
    if self.prepare_state is True:
        raise StateError
```

Does this make sense? It reminds me a bit of a Singleton or the State pattern and it reminds me of a mutex which I haven't really worked with before. Is there a design pattern for what I'm trying to do? I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so any keywords as to what I should search for are welcome.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Python, although I'm also happy about language independent ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[State Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) seems to be an overkill for your use case. It would have made sense if you had more complicated rules for state changes, such as allow `final_calculation` only if `prepare` of both `B` and `C` has been called once, or something.

Your current implementation is straightforward and looks good. You can also consider renaming `prepare_state` to `is_final_calculation_allowed` or `is_prepare_done` to make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I guess I mainly wanted to make sure I'm not doing something that seems really strange to others.